# Laravel whereJsonContains in Eloquent giving no results

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In the last version of Laravel you have an option to check if Json values are cotaining some values.
Why doesn't this `whereJsonContains` works like I expected it to work:

```
$users = User::whereJsonContains('options->foobar', 96)->get();
```

This is what is stored in the `options` column (for example):

```
{"foobar":[96,11,271,256],"sheep":[80,111]}
```

What I want is to get all Users that have the value 96 in the 'foobar' array.

What is the correct way to do so?

This is the query when I dump it with `->toSql()`:

```
select * from "users" where ("options"->'foobar')::jsonb @> ?
```

So the question is:
*How can I show all users that have value `96` in the `foobar` array of the JSON?*

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: could you please provide not sql dump, but some db records and output of the sql?

Comment: there is no output.

Comment: @user1469734 `whereIsActive(true)` - does the row your expecting is `active` ?

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam removed it from the example

Comment: `$users` is empty? Are the values in `foobar` integers or strings? What's your PostgreSQL version?